# ComboBox refreshes ListBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have visual studio 2010.

I have a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) and a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx), if you select a item from the listbox and after you click the combobox, the listbox refresh. It's like clearing the combobox and adding the items again.

**If you open a new project, add a ListBox, add some items to the ListBox, add a ComboBox, run the project, select one item from the ListBox, click the ComboBox and the ListBox for some reason refreshes.**

Anyone knows why it happens?

If some can try it, to see if it is an issue with VB, or some setting in my program.

Comment: No, people can't know, because they don't know your code. Provide it and People may help you.

Comment: Nice find.  Happens in c#, too, just to verify.

Comment: What it could be LarsTech??

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer: [Listbox flicker when combo box drops down](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/fb199dec-1b23-4416-8aa5-dba79856a963/)

It suggests using this version of the ListBox (I translated it from c#) and it worked for me:

```
Public Class MyListBox
  Inherits ListBox

  Private WM_KILLFOCUS As Integer = &H8

  Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg <> WM_KILLFOCUS Then
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```